# Classic ASP passing object into VB6 COM dll method - Type Mismatch

Tags: com, asp-classic, marshalling

This is one of the more bizarre issues I have faced in my time, and it's best explained like many problems with an example in Classic ASP:

```
Set thing = Server.CreateObject("ClassName") ' a C++ COM dll class
Set tool = Server.CreateObject("OtherClassName") ' a VB6 COM dll class
```

this doesn't work

```
tool.Method thing
```

this does work

```
Set session("thing") = thing
tool.Method session("thing")
```

When it doesn't work I get a type mismatch, I am VERY perplexed and have no idea where to start on this to be honest. Any pointers people?

Comment: The method param is not a byref but I think your idea that passing it from session could modify how the object is represented in terms of vtable type has to be worth looking into. Thanks!

Comment: The VB6 COM dll method didn't define ByVal or ByRef (doesn't it use ByVal by default?), when I changed this to ByVal it worked with either session or local defined variable! Thanks YMS for the suggestion, I wonder if there is a way to trace the parameter type (just out of interest)

Comment: I think VB expects COM objects and strings(VT_BSTR) to be ByRef by default, although I could not find a reference to confirm this statement.

Comment: For tracing the parameter type you may try the (vbscript) function [VarType](http://w3schools.com/vbscript/func_vartype.asp), but I am not sure if it is available in asp or what he behaviour will be for VT_BYREF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic VB may expect the parameter of tool.Method to be a variant with type VT_BYREF, maybe your C++ COM instance is been passed as VT_DISPATCH or VT_UNKNOWN instead, but it is transformed into a VT_BYREF when you store it in a session first.